# comparing strings with leading zeroes

Tags: php

I need to check if two strings (numbers) are the same.  However if one of the strings has a leading zero, then all bets are off - it says they are equal:

```
$hospitalno1 = "64583";                 
$hospitalno2 = "064583";

if ($hospitalno1 <> $hospitalno2){ 
    echo "Different";
}
```

How can I compare these two variables as strings rather than as numbers?

Comment: Note, this exact same problem happens with in_array(), make sure to pass in third property: true.

Answer (score 4):

Just use:

```
<?php
$hospitalno1 = "64583";                 
$hospitalno2 = "064583";

if ($hospitalno1 !== $hospitalno2){ 
    echo "Different";
} 
else
{
  echo "same"  ;
}

?>
```

The `!==` will do a stringent datatype + value check and will alert if anything is different.

Comment: Many thanks for that - I've never realised the difference between <> and !== before.

Answer (score 0):

Cast them to `int`:

```
$hospitalno1 = "64583";                 
$hospitalno2 = "064583";

if ((int)$hospitalno1 != (int)$hospitalno2){ 
    echo "Different";
}
```

yet beware "this string" will become `0`, so add `is_int()` prior conversion.

Also instead of `<>` you should use `!=` despite the fact the former will work in PHP, the latter is cross language standard.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't want the strings to be type juggled.

```
<> type juggles to match types before comparison, 
   causing your strings to be ints
!== is a comparitor that doesn't type juggle before comparison
```

Here's a rundown on comparison operators:
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

You just have to make use of `!==` which will not ignore type otherwise type will be ignored

```
$hospitalno1 = "64583";                 
$hospitalno2 = "064583";

if ($hospitalno1 !== $hospitalno2){ 
    echo "Diffrent";
}
```

[DEMO](https://3v4l.org/a1r6e)

Answer (score 0):

You are very close.
Just pre-concatenate them with another string character, `a`, `-`, anything will do

```
$hospitalno1 = '64583';
    $hospitalno1 = 'a-'. $hospitalno1;
$hospitalno2 = '064583';
    $hospitalno2 = 'a-'. $hospitalno2;

if ($hospitalno1 <> $hospitalno2){ 
    echo "Different";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
<?php 
$hospitalno1 = (string)"64583";                 
$hospitalno2 = (string)"064583";

if ($hospitalno1 !== $hospitalno2){ 
    echo "Different";
} 
?>
```

my php code link >> [Code](https://eval.in/874837)